# Which Eclipse version should I use for an Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am starting to develop Android applications. Which version of Eclipse should I use?

I see there are 11 versions. I am confused with these:

1. Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
2. Eclipse Classic 3.6.1
3. Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
4. Pulsar for Mobile Developers

Comment: As this questions is 9 month old now, can you testify that the best-rated answer below is still the best?

Comment: actually that was the quickest answer and helped me a lot saving my time. I was satisfied with that and it deserves best answer.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**Update July 2017:**

From [ADT Plugin page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), the question must be unasked:

**The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported, as per [this announcement in June 2015](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html).**

The Eclipse ADT plugin has many known bugs and potential security bugs that will not be fixed.

You should immediately switch to use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), the official IDE for Android. For help transitioning your projects, read Migrate to Android Studio.

Comment: from the android developer link, I see this one [http://eclipse.org/mobile/](http://eclipse.org/mobile/). probably an optimized version for mobile developers

Comment: @Jeff Axelrod Did you mean Eclipse Classic 3.6.1 ?

Comment: I just get the bundle. On a side-note, I am *SO* ready to switch to Android Studio !

Comment: FYI, nowadays the answer is to migrate your development from Eclipse to Android Studio:  https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html  , or if starting today, skip Eclipse entirely:  https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Answer (score 21):

The *easiest* solution is to download the Android SDK bundle:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

> The ADT Bundle provides everything you need to start developing apps,
>   including a version of the Eclipse IDE with built-in ADT (Android
>   Developer Tools) to streamline your Android app development.

Comment: Google has hi-jacked that link and it now goes to the install for Android Studio.  I hated Android Studio and never got out of gradle hell.  Maybe I'm dumb.  - back to eclipse for me.

Answer (score 7):

I literally did this 1 hour ago.

1. [SDK R7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. [Get Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) - if you don't have (its the first image link JDK)
3. [Get Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) - it's the first on the list with the most downloads
4. [Android Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Download the appropriate files for your OS. The Android SDK needs java in order to install. Once you get the Android SDK installed go get eclipse and install that. Basically download the file and unzip then in a directory. The android install is the same but it will install a lot more files. (5) Finally open eclipse and go to help > install new software >> and add the url to the plugin - I used this one https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: See my notes about Android Plugin (ADT) and Helios incompatibility.  It may appear to work initially, but it's currently not recommended by the Android ADT developers.

Comment: ok, I see. I had some erros, not sure where they were coming from.

Answer (score 7):

Released in June 2012, [Eclipse for Mobile Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-mobile-developers/junosr1) is an awesome starting point for developers looking to focus on Android development. I've used it for several projects since August and haven't been disappointed.

Comment: I've been using this, but it seems to have no support for html/javascript files.  If you're writing apps in html/javascript/PhoneGap this is a problem.  Navigated here while trying to find the solution.

Answer (score 5):

> **June 2012 **

**Google Recommends Eclipse Helios, Eclipse Classic or Eclipse RCP**. For details, read the below post.

**URL:** http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Look under *ADT 18.0.0 (April 2012)*.

**Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6.2) or higher is required for ADT 18.0.0.**

Look under *Installing the ADT Plugin*.

If you need to install or update Eclipse, you can download it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. The "**Eclipse Classic**" version is recommended. Otherwise, a Java or RCP version of Eclipse is recommended.

> **April 2014 Updated**

**Eclipse Indigo (Version 3.7.2) or higher is required.** I'll suggest you to use Eclipse Kepler.

**ADT 22.6.0 (March 2014)**

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse 3.5 for Java Developer is the best option for you and 3.6 version is good but not at all because of compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

As of 10/2011 ... classic is fine for Android development.

See [Compare Eclipse Packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php) for a nice chart.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just getting into Android, you would be well served by using [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) rather than using any version of Eclipse.  Android Studio was released in 2013 and provides a nice integrated development environment for developing for Android.

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ, which is a great java devlopment environment.  It also has these specific Android features:

- Gradle-based build support.
- Android-specific refactoring and quick fixes.
- Lint tools to catch performance, usability, version compatibility and other problems.
- ProGuard and app-signing capabilities.
- Template-based wizards to create common Android designs and components.
- A rich layout editor that allows you to drag-and-drop UI components, preview layouts on multiple screen configurations, and much more.

You can [download it here.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Comment: Caution: Android Studio is currently available as an early access preview. Several features are either incomplete or not yet implemented and you may encounter bugs.

Comment: Caution?  It works great!  If you are learning, learn the IntelliJ based systems, like Android Studio.  Don't burn brain cycles with Eclipse.

Comment: If I were a beginner Android developer && involved in a commercial project (versus a pet one) I would still use Eclipse for now because of risks. That caution is taken from the official site, so they probably have reasons for declaring that.

Comment: Have you used IntelliJ before?  All of my close circle of professional Android developers have been on IntelliJ for quite some time, and have moved over to Android Studio.  The cautions remind me of typical warnings that are prompted by horrible U.S. attorneys.  Kind of like "Caution- hot coffee is hot.  I just hate the idea of someone wasting time figuring out how to develop in Eclipse, only to have to change over to IntelliJ later.

Comment: :) OK, while in general I support using this new tool, I just wanted to mention there is another side of the medal. I would refrain from further comments, since this is not a chat and finally picking an IDE has a "matter of taste" component.

Answer (score 0):

> The ADT plug-in is yet not compatible
>   with 3.6

I have been using Eclipse 3.6 with ADT for the past three months for developing applications on Android. I haven't faced any issues so far. It really good and working fine.

Comment: From the Android system requirements page:  "Caution: There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice."  P.S., you may want to address replies like this as comments, not answers.

Comment: oops.. i am sorry.. i dint knew that.. shall i delete the post??

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use the free community version of Intellij Idea 11+. The ADT eclipse plugin is always having problems.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26774

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Eclipse Indigo EE* version for Android development. It is quite good, and I haven't faced any issues so far.

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's not on here [Nvidia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia) has a nice package that simplifies getting it set up and running with an added bonus of supporting 3D acceleration on capable TEGRA enabled devices.

You may find it [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend at least Eclipse Indigo (v 3.7) for Android Development because even though a minimum of Helios (v 3.6) is required for ADT 22.0.1 as explained here...

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

... Indigo is required for Android NDK development using CDT, as explained here:

http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin

Answer (score 0):

Get the full Android-SDK plus the dependencies 
at [**http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Do have Java installed :)