# 'required items could not be found' error when installing ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Development Tools 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431)
>     Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431) requires 'org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Some info:

1. Eclipse SDK Version: 3.6.2
2. jdk-6u26-windows-i586
3. Windows 7

Any suggestions on how to solve this 'required items could not be found' error?

Answer (score 80):

Have had the same problem a few times. You need to add the following urls to the "Available Software Sites" of your eclipse installation:

- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
- http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7

That should fix it.

If not, see my install paths, and add as needed:

[image]

Also, make sure you tick the box on install that says "Contact all update sites during install to find required software".

Comment: First URL getting error:                                                                        Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  org.eclipse.linuxtools.callgraph.feature.group [0.0.2.201106060936] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.

Comment: You could first try to update your eclipse to 3.7? Indigo is the code name for 3.7.

Comment: Updated to eclipse 3.7

still getting error on adt installing - same error
on intalling http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

getting error:

`
The following software cannot be installed because it is intended for use only in Plug-in Development Environment (PDE) target platforms. Please deselect these items and retry the operation.
  Gyrex Target Components (Incubation) 0.10.0.v20110525-1130-19B-EOBKvx0z-On1fJnz0Q-x6BpG`

Comment: Are you trying to install software from that url? You shouldn't do that. You should just make sure that your "Software paths" contain all the necessary urls, like in my screenshot, so that the  Android Developer tools install can find the required libraries. Do you have any other plugins installed?

Comment: Oh my god =) The bigest error ever, thank's. You are right I was trying to install software from that url =). Now everything ok.

Comment: FYI folks, this works if you are running a different version of eclipse, but you have to change the urls appropriately. I.e. for 3.5/galileo it's http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo and
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.5

Comment: Yep, this was the problem. Thanks! Google should add this info in their ADT installation guide at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html.

Comment: I had the same problem with Eclipse Juno 4.2 in Windows 7 64 bit. Following @BramVandenbussche's solution solved it..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android Bundle
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

(see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14754583/414969)

Comment: That;s given answer isn't perfect solution as question asked!

Comment: But using the Android Bundle will fix his current problem and other possible problems in the future. Google recommends using it ..