# How can I fix this error when installing ADT on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, eclipse

I do not know much about Eclipse, but according to [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing) everything should work fine (I am using the .zip archive). The error seems to occur only when Android Development Tools are checked.

Here is the full error code:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>
> Software being installed: Android Development Tools 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431)
>
> Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 12.0.0.v201106281929-138431) requires 'org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0' but it could not be found.

Comment: What is your eclipse and ubuntu version?

Comment: Eclipse Gallileo.Ubuntu 11.10.None of the plugins seem to work now when installed throught apt-get.When I downloaded the binaries from the site,everything seemed to work.The problem is:I installed plugins on apt-get got eclipse and now I get duplicate location error when trying to install on Indigo(downloaded from their site).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer from the Eclipse forums [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/222154/710015/#msg_710015)

> At the available software window, click on the link "Available software sites".
>   You need two items checked, the Android Plugin that you added and the download.eclipse.org/releases/helios or galilio if that is your version of eclipse. Click ok to go back to the available software window.
>   Now select Work with: Android plugin.
>   Now click next continuing with install.

Steps:

1. Help > Install New Software
2. type or paste: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo (change to match your version of eclipse then click Add)
3. Click Cancel, go back to Install New Software and choose the Android related repository. ie. http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

Note that sometimes you need to use the http, not https link for the ADT repository (the https did not work for me).

Comment: This answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082158/required-items-could-not-be-found-error-when-installing-adt-plugin

Comment: works right with the 'http' not 'https', Thanks @AbdallahDeeb