# Unable to Install ADT in Win7 64 bit

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, windows-7-x64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘required items could not be found’ error when installing ADT plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082158/required-items-could-not-be-found-error-when-installing-adt-plugin)

I am a newbie to android development. I was able to set up the entire environment and run a few andriod app examples at my workplace. at work I use windows 7, 32bit.

I wanted to try somethings at home so attempted to set up the same environment at home on windows 7 64 bit OS.

I downloaded 64 bit versions of the required software:

**Eclipse 4.2 Juno**,
**Android ADK**
**64 bit JDK**.

But now whenever i try to install the ADT plugin for eclipse it shows error:

"**Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 21.0.1.v201212060256-543035 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group** "

I googled this all day and attempted all the possible solutions like running with admin privileges, using http and all the sort but no help.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Astor! No idea how i missed that quesion.. that saved my day!! thanks a lot buddy! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem, i never found out how to get around the error but this download included everything ready to go and set up. Download the whole bundle rather then the option to use an existing IDE

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html