# MultiTouchEvent Error?

Tags: java, android

getting a few error and not sure what to do please help.

```
The method getX() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
The method getY() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
The method getX() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
The method getY() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
The method getPointerCount() is undefined for the type MotionEvent  
The method getPointerId(int) is undefined for the type MotionEvent  
ACTION_POINTER_DOWN cannot be resolved or is not a field    
The method getX() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
The method getY() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int) 
ACTION_POINTER_UP cannot be resolved or is not a field  MultiTouchHandler.java  
ACTION_MASK cannot be resolved or is not a field    
ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK cannot be resolved or is not a field 
ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT cannot be resolved or is not a field
The method getPointerId(int) is undefined for the type MotionEvent
```

The code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {  
    synchronized (this) {  
        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;  
        int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >>   MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;  
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);   

        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
            touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN;
            touchEvent.pointer = pointerId;
            touchEvent.x = touchX[pointerId] = (int) (event
                    .getX(pointerIndex) * scaleX);
            touchEvent.y = touchY[pointerId] = (int) (event
                    .getY(pointerIndex) * scaleY);
            isTouched[pointerId] = true;
            touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
            touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP;
            touchEvent.pointer = pointerId;
            touchEvent.x = touchX[pointerId] = (int) (event
                    .getX(pointerIndex) * scaleX);
            touchEvent.y = touchY[pointerId] = (int) (event
                    .getY(pointerIndex) * scaleY);
            isTouched[pointerId] = false;
            touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++) {
                pointerIndex = i;
                pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);

                touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
                touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_DRAGGED;
                touchEvent.pointer = pointerId;
                touchEvent.x = touchX[pointerId] = (int) (event
                        .getX(pointerIndex) * scaleX);
                touchEvent.y = touchY[pointerId] = (int) (event
                        .getY(pointerIndex) * scaleY);
                touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);
            }
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've imported the right `MotionEvent`? You need `android.view.MotionEvent`.

Comment: yes i have wish i could show all of my code

Answer (score 0):

Reading the first error:

```
The method getX() in the type MotionEvent is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

This says getX() on MotionEvent cannot be called with an int as the arguments ie getX(1)

In your code I can see:

```
touchEvent.x = touchX[pointerId] = (int) (event.getX(pointerIndex) * scaleX);
```

If you see you are calling getX(pointerIndex). This is a compilation error.

If you read the other errors and look at your code you should be able to find them all.

My advice: Get an IDE (see [Which Eclipse version should I use for an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792306/which-eclipse-version-should-i-use-for-android-app) to help choose) and all these issues will be helpfully highlighted in red for you.

Comment: ok makes sense i am trying to develop using api level 3 and using the newest version of eclipse