# What Version of Eclipse do I use for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am sure this has been asked before, but I can not find a good answer. I want to create an Android app, I want to use Eclipse, but there are so many versions on the downloads page, and I am not sure which one I should use ... some of these include

```
>Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
>Eclipse Classic 4.2.2
>Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
>Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
>Eclipse for Mobile Developers
```

Thank You :)

Comment: I'm using Eclipse for Mobile Developers. I seem to remember it already having all of the needed requisite plugins already (except for ADT).

Comment: Neither of them. Save your nerves and use IntelliJ. Or Android Studio (when it's out of beta stage).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Eclipse version should I use for Android app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792306/which-eclipse-version-should-i-use-for-android-app)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would recommend [the ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), as it has a suitable version of Eclipse, plus the necessary Android plumbing, in one download.

Comment: Thank you, I was scared that I would download the wrong version :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on what you want to use in Eclipse. If you are just starting in the Eclipse world go for the smallest (lightweight) packages because they will also make your Eclipse experience smoother (loading, UI, etc.). From your list above I would choose Classic, but, if you ONLY want to focus on Android development, you could try the Google prepackaged version of Eclipse (ADT, see below).

You can install either:

- standalone Eclipse plus the ADT plugins or
- the prepackaged version of Eclipse with ADT provided by Google (recommended)

If you already have an Eclipse installed (which you probably want if you already use Eclipse and want to keep the existing worspaces/preferences/etc.) you can only install the ADT plugins from **[here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)**. And both Indigo and Juno versions of Eclipse should work. Of course that you should try and upgrade your workspace first to Juno and than install the ADT plugins to avoid any other surprises.

The Google prepackaged version of Eclipse is **[here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)** and will give you less headaches because you have almost everything into it. You only have to use the prepackaged download manager inside Eclipse to download platform versions and device images (and many other tools and examples). This will use Eclipse Juno version.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the classic version, but in my opinion intelliJ is better
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Google has just announced at Google I/O a new IDE called "Android Studio" which
is based on IntelliJ and can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Answer (score 1):

Any will do, but the most recommended one is Mobile. Also check the new IDE that Google released just for that ([Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)).

Comment: Oh, I haven't even of this, would you recommend Android Studio over Eclipse?

Comment: I can't recommend it as I haven't personally tested it yet. While it is much more Android oriented than Eclipse, and made by none other than Google, it is still relatively new. But IMO, it wouldn't hurt to try it.

Comment: Android Studio is in its beta version. I would rather hang on until the stable version is officially released.

Comment: Doesn't even start on my win 7 64 bit..Woudn't recommend. IntelliJ is probably better but it doesn't show errors on gradle builds..So i might just go to eclipse

Answer (score 0):

- Download Eclipse Installer from https://www.eclipse.org/ (top right
  corner)
- After downloading start installer.
- Check if there is an option as "for Android Developers". If there is
  not,  click the updates button on top right corner. It downloads
  updates for installer. After the download is completed check again
  the list.
- Download Eclipse for Android Developers.